# If I 'start' a process in a TeamCity build will it be removed when the build completes?

Tags: teamcity

If I have a TeamCity installation on Windows and I spawn a process with a windows `start` command (actually I am starting a Puma/Rack webserver) will the process created by that start command be automatically removed when the build job completes?

Does TeamCity provide an isolated process space for each build job on Windows?

Or should I clean up after myself?

Comment: No, the spawned process will not be killed. If you want it killed, you will need to handle it in your build script. Why are you asking?

Comment: I am asking because it was difficult to shut down a spawned process when I am using Windows.  I ended up writing some PowerShell script to shut it down.